# create a 2nd layer nested object to update data in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Thanks for your help.

P/G: Angular 14 with Typescript

I'd like to create a nested Object with a loop. So, I can generate a Mat-Tree in angular later. This photo comes from Angular's offical mat-tree example.

Ultimately, I'd like to create something like this and fully customize every name of parent's node and child node.
[image]

1. I want to create a variable with interface which represent like below.
   for example:

```
    export interface CellLeaderTree{
      name: string;
    
      child: CellMemberTree;
    }
    export interface CellMemberTree {
      childName: string;
      hasChild: boolean;
    }
```

I have tried like this:

```
    const obj1 = {} as CellLeaderTree;
      obj1.name = 'Young';    // this works.
      // obj1.child = "me";      // this does not work.
      // obj1.child.hasChild = true;    // this does not work.
      // obj1.child.childName = "test";    // this does not work.
      //obj1.child.childName = "Mike";       // this does not work.
      //  obj1.child.hasChild = true;    // this does not work.
```

Could you help me to create a object variable with nested with children?

2. In the above Tree, I want to update every name of the tree.
   for example, I want to change "Groceries".
   Also, I want to change all of Groceries' children.
   Also, I want to able to change "Fruits" and its children.

In order to do like above, how should i structure my interface and create object in typescripts?

** Input Data as a replacement of Top Tree node name such as Groceries :

```
["Mike", "David","Vic"];
```

** first layer of children such as "Amond Meal flour"... or Fruits":

```
["child1", "child2", "child3"]
```

** 2nd layer of children such as "Apple":

```
["grand-child1", "grand-child2"]
```

-- error message:
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'childName')

Thanks again,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create two interfaces:

```
export interface CellLeaderTree {
    name: string; // the name of the cell 
    children: CellMiddleTree[];
  }

 export interface CellMiddleTree {
    name: string;
    children: string []; // this can contain only simple children
  }
```

then simply:

```
obj1: CellLeaderTree = { name: 'Young', children: [
   {name: 'child', children: ['grand child 1', 'grand child 1']
]};
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment. it helped a lot. But i am still struggling. My question is how to generate this kind of data structure with any kind of loop. how to change each node name too because this data set has null value for each item. how to change Key value for each parent node. 
const TREE_DATA = {
      Groceries: {
        'Almond Meal flour': null,
        Fruits: {
          Apple: null,
          Berries: ['Blueberry', 'Raspberry'],
        },
      },
      Reminders: ['Cook dinner', 'Read the Material Design spec'],
    };